# live video streaming from python open cv to FE angular

Tags: python, opencv, media, ant-media-server-sdk

I have my python code which will read a video from localfile system triggers a ML model and saves the video to localfile system continuously using open cv.
here instead of storing it to localfile system i was to stream it to FE application.
I am having a web browser based angular application which needs to display this video live.
How can this be achieved.